# Totally independent jobs on same data on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming

I need to optimize some hyperparameters for a machine learning problem.  This involves launching many jobs on the same input data and saving their outputs, completely independently of each other. On every job distribution system that I've ever used, this is a very common use case, which is handled with a few switches on the command line and/or a job config file. Now I'm on a cluster whose job distribution system is Hadoop/Yarn, which I haven't used before. Despite much searching, the only way to do this on Hadoop seems to be to submit each run as a separate job. This would incur the job submission overhead for each run, of which there can be 1000's. Is there a simple way around that?  Maybe some kind of MR job without any R? (BTW, my ML code is in C++ so I guess I need to use Hadoop Streaming.) I'll learn Java if I have to, but it seems like a disproportionate amount of effort for something so simple.

Comment: It isn't too clear what you're asking. Its common to have multiple jobs reading the same input at the same time, they are just submitted as separate jobs.

Comment: @BinaryNerd Thanks for the comment.  I clarified the question in response.